Will open, edit, store from/to lossy audio format significantly degrade quality?
Say I have files only available as "ogg vorbis", 44.1kHz at 128 kbps vbr - which are meant for archival, but not much storage for lossless was available at the time.
These are to be kept for later analysis, both by trained ear and/or numerical means.
They contain partly long sections of irrelevant information and silence/noise, and their use would be more practical when those sections were mostly cut out.
Does doing that, then "saving" (i.e. re-encoding) the file after editing, assuming the same outout as input formats / encoding settings are used, significantly reduce the quality of these recordings, with regards to human or machine analysis?
If so, would using a higher bitrate for re-encoding ameliorate it?
My naive view of this would be that, any processing with e.g. float32 adds noise, but I have no idea whether that could influence enough what the encoder does w.r.t. the signal that was already once processed. If nothing was changed, ideally, it would find the frequencies removed as psychoacoustic strategies for compression already not being present and the output should be very close to the same as the input signal - but this naive view perhaps doesn't account for things being "spoilt" by slightly altered numbers in processing?
There is a similar question on SuperUser, with a not very detailed answer, and it's about a different format (mp3).

This really depends a lot on what exactly the processing is. Cutting out unwanted parts of the signal will have very little impact on the parts that you keep. Ogg Vorbis is block based and the largest block size is 8192 samples. Even that is rare, and most encoding is done at 1024 samples or less. So we are talking a few tens of milliseconds.
Assuming that you don't do any other processing (like filtering, phase adjustments', denoising, etc.) the re-encode will indeed add more noise to the signal. You can expect your signal to noise ratio to decrease by about 3 dB. Whether this is a problem are not depends a lot on the specific type of signal, it's sample rate, number of channels, and what exactly you are trying to do with it. 128 kb/s should be plenty for any speech application. However, it's not great for critical music listening and the extra noise may be an issue.
A higher bit rate format would certainly help here and reduce the additional noise. If you want to be super safe, you can just use Flac which does not add any noise at all, but typically comes in around 1000 kb/s. Ogg at 256 kb/s reduces the extra noise to about 1 dB and 320 kb/s to 0.8dB. Spotify uses 256 kb/s and 320 kb/s  for the Premium and Connect users with many happy customers, so depending in your application, this may be a "reasonable" choice.

And if I remember correctly, at least the ffmpeg/avcodec family of codecs can be used for lossless cutting  – if aligned to block durations. The trick really is to just hand through the unmodified payload bits and just regenerate time stamps, metadata entries. Haven't tried that, but if you don't like the ffmpeg command line, there's a GUI thing.

Good point, but I'm not sure it works with Ogg since the blocks are overlapped.

My guess is that what you could do is simulate a packet loss and have the decoder interpolate the "binding" block between the last of the previous section and the first of the next, or you insert an all-zero block. Memory is fuzzy, but I think a vorbis file keeps around a book of low-resolution "floor" spectra, and just saves the index into that table per block, plus quantized residuals. If the floors on both ends are the same, no problem, you should be able to interpolate the residuals, if they're not, hm. Maybe one really has no choice but to re-encode the overlapping frames?
